# How to perform multiple string operations on Bash variable with least steps?

Tags: bash, git, variables, git-bash, string-operations

I have gitbash installed in Windows 10 64bit, but I assume the solution I am asking will work in both Linux Git and Win GitBash.

I have defined the `BRNCH` variable to do multiple commit and merge operations involving the current branch, so I have declared current branch like below:

```
BRNCH=`git branch --show-current`
```

Now I want to get the Ticket ID (which is usually the capital of branch name discarding any versions like `-v1`,`-v2` .... and keeping the digits as it is) from the branch name in the same current branch variable, and I am trying below, but this doesn't work:

```
echo ${BRNCH%-*^^}
```

So for eg. if the branch name I have is `abc-123-v3` the above code which is expected to perform multiple string operations and print `ABC-123`, doesn't even do single operation, but this works and gives me `abc-123`:

```
echo ${BRNCH%-*}
```

I don't know very deep about Bash coding, so I assumed something like **nested brace pairs with order precedence**(this could be possible future enhancement in Bash and GitBash :)) might work and applied this, but that too didn't work:

```
echo ${{BRNCH%-*}^^}
```

So how to do multiple string operations on bash variable with **just one or fewest lines of code and steps** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So for eg. if the branch name I have is `abc-123-v3` the above code which is expected to perform multiple string operations and print `ABC-123`

What's wrong with

```
v=${BRNCH%-*}
echo ${v^^}
```

?

You can hide the temp and save yourself later trouble,

```
ticketfor() { local v=${1%-*}; echo ${v^^}; }

ticketfor $BRNCH
```